# OSTicket sending emails through localhost/sendmail even though I've specified the SMTP server to use in settings

Tags: php, smtp, osticket

I don't know if this is a configuration issue in OSTicket, or PHP, or what.
In OSTicket for the email address being configured, the section "labeled Sending email via SMTP"
is filled in with enabled radio button selected, hostname, port, and authentication required is set as well, as it uses the same authentication that the imap receiver users.

When I test sending an email and look at all the headers, it went directly from this machine to the destination (using local mail server), it completely bypassed the SMTP server configured in OSTicket. I am using OSTicket v1.10.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look also to:

Admin Panel=>Email=>Settings=>Default MTA

You can select what MTA to use as default.